# Haskell 2D points distance and length

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

```
-- (edit)
-- Punkt = Point
-- Streckenzug = Polygonal chain
-- distanz = distance
-- laenge = length
-- (/edit)

data Punkt = Punkt 
  { x :: Float
  , y :: Float 
  }

p1 (x1, x2) =(x1,x2)
p2 (y1, y2) =(y1,y2)


data Streckenzug = Streckenzug {
streckenzug :: [Punkt..]
}  

distanz :: Punkt -> Punkt -> Float
distanz (x1,y1) (x2,y2) = sqrt (x' * x' + y' * y')
 where
 x'= x1-x2
 y'= y1-y2


laenge :: Streckenzug -> Float
laenge (x:xs) = if length Streckenzug < 2
                    then Streckenzug
                    else sum([distanz p1 p2 | (p1,p2) <- xs ]  )
```

Could somebody tell me why I am getting the parse error on Streckenzug?
The errors that Haskell puts out aren't really helpful.

We have the data Punkt which shall be a point in a two dimensional coordinateesystem
and the data Streckenzug which is a list of points
later on the functions distanz and laenge (length) shall give us the as the sum between adjacent points .

Comment: You have many formatting errors, and on line 10-12, you have `data Streckenzug` with a member also named `Streckenzug`

Comment: A record member name can not start with an uppercase, or at least not without some extensions.

Comment: I would recommend copying your code into a file, and then in the same directory start `ghci` and then `:load FILENAME.hs`.  GHCI will parse and attempt to load your code.  You'll see a number of type mismatches and invocation errors.

Answer (score 1):

The errors that GHC produces are most certainly helpful. Let's go through them one by one.

Firstly, I get no parse error whatsoever, as long as I remove the spurious indentation at the start. Instead, I get this error:

> ```
> main.hs:11:17: error:
>     Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘Punkt..’
>     No module named ‘Punkt’ is imported.
> ```

Looking at the relevant line, I see you've written `Punkt..` for no reason. This means nothing. This should just be `Punkt`. here is the correction, with better indentation.

```
data Streckenzug = Streckenzug {
    streckenzug :: [Punkt] -- Correction here
}
```

When I fix this, the errors change. Let's go to the next:

> ```
> main.hs:15:9: error:
>     • Couldn't match expected type ‘Punkt’
>                   with actual type ‘(Float, Float)’
> ```

Looking at the relevant line, I see that you're not matching on `Punkt`, but actually on `(Float, Float)`s. This is trivial to fix. Here is the solution, with better indentation:

```
distanz :: Punkt -> Punkt -> Float
distanz pkt1 pkt2 = sqrt (x' * x' + y' * y') -- Correction here
 where
   x'= x pkt1 - x pkt2
   y'= y pkt1 - y pkt2 -- Note the adjustment here.
```

Please understand that a `Punkt` is not simply a tuple of floats; it's treated seperately by the compiler.

Unfortunately, I would try to correct your function `laenge`, but I cannot at all work out what you mean by it – the types are completely broken, and your intention is unclear. I would recommend learning from the above mistakes and trying again.

All in all, however, the following file works:

```
data Punkt = Punkt 
  { x :: Float
  , y :: Float 
  }

data Streckenzug = Streckenzug {
    streckenzug :: [Punkt]
}  

distanz :: Punkt -> Punkt -> Float
distanz pkt1 pkt2 = sqrt (x' * x' + y' * y')
  where
    x'= x pkt1 - x pkt2
    y'= y pkt1 - y pkt2
```

The functions `p1` and `p2` are completely useless and so I've removed them; not only are they identical, but also are both of type `p1, p2 :: (a,b) -> (a,b)`, in other words `p1 = p2 = id`.

Comment: `laenge` was supposed to compute the total length of a polygonal chain, I think...

Comment: Thank you for helping me. if you have any reliable sources except learnyouahaskell i would be grateful if you let me know. By means of your help that the errors are of very simple nature. And andrey is absolutely right.

Comment: After trying to get a Solution for the example distanz pkt1 1.0 1.0 pkt2 2.0 2.0  I just got the error message variable not in scope pkt1 :: Punkt , Variable not in scope : pkt2 . Can anybody tell me the reason?

Comment: @disccco If you have another question, ask another question; do *not* post a comment.